# Extracting 'single item' from Multi Dimensional Array (c#)

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Say I have the code

```
var marray = new int[,]{{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}};
```

Is it possible to get a reference to the first item  - i.e. something that looked like:

```
var _marray = marray[0];
//would look like: var _marray = new int[,]{{0,1}};
```

Instead, when referencing `marray` from a one dimensional context, it sees `marray` as having  length of 6

(i.e. `new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5}`)

Comment: Have you considered `Tuple<int, int>[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a jagged array

```
var marray = new[] { new[] { 0, 1 }, new[] { 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5 } };
Console.WriteLine(marray[0][1]);
```

Comment: A multidimensional array is nice because all my data has a fixed number of dimensions, whereas if someone were to copy a staggered / jagged array they could insert an array with any number of items to the 'master' array.